# convert array into an array of ojects

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object, underscore.js

I have the following array list.

```
var data = [ "USA", "Denmark", "London"];
```

I need to convert it in this form

```
var data = [
 { "id" : 1, "label": "USA" },
 { "id" : 2, "label": "Denmark" },
 { "id" : 3, "label": "London" }
];
```

Can anyone please let me know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pretty easy using `Array.map` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var formatted = data.map(function(country, index) {
    return { id: (index + 1), label: country }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple version:

```
var convertedData = []
for (var i in data){
  convertedData.push({id: i+1, label: data[i]});
}

data = convertedData; //if you want to overwrite data variable
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `forEach` to loop through the data array

```
var data = [ "USA", "Denmark", "London"];
var demArray =[];
data.forEach(function(item,index){
demArray.push({
 id:index+1,
 label:item
})

})
console.log(demArray)
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/5v98v5gs/)

Answer (score 1):

[`Underscore`](http://underscorejs.org/#map) way (for old browsers without [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) support):

```
var res = _.map(data, function(p, i){
    return {id: i + 1, label: p};
});
```